# ElasticSearch. Priority does not work

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a wrong results when I use cross_fields search
When i send this query

```
{'from': 0, 
 'sort': ['_score'],
 'size': 400,
 'query': {
       'bool': 
           {'must': 
               {'multi_match': 
                   {'type': 'cross_fields', 
                    'fields': ['nickname^1', 'pedigree_name^0.4', 'breed^0.2', 'city^0.1', 'country^0.05'],
                    'operator': 'and',
                    'query': 'Akita'}
               }
           }
   }
}
```

I get this results
[image]

But why? Pedigree_name priority are higher then breed priority

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is that your query type is 'cross_fields'. It "analyzes the query string into individual terms, then looks for each term in any of the fields, as though they were one big field." Further rom [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields):

> Note that cross_fields is usually only useful on short string fields
>   that all have a boost of 1. Otherwise boosts, term freqs and length
>   normalization contribute to the score in such a way that the blending
>   of term statistics is not meaningful anymore.